# how to chang to value in Skscene?

Tags: swift, swiftui

how to chang to value in Skscene ?
i have a class (xiangcene) and the time1 need to change through the button. how can i do that?

```
struct xiang: View {
    @ObservedObject var skc = xiangcene()
    var xiangview:SKScene {
        let scene = xiangcene()
        scene.scaleMode = .fill
        return scene
    }
    var body: some View {
        ZStack{
            SpriteView(scene: xiangview)
            Button("timeset"){
                skc.time1 = 60 // it no change the value
            }
        }
    }
}
class xiangcene:SKScene,ObservableObject{
    @Published var time1 = 1

    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

        let wait1 = SKAction.wait(forDuration: TimeInterval(time1))
        let seque = SKAction.sequence([wait1])
        self.run(seque)
    }
```

Comment: You're creating two different instances of `xiangcene` -- one on your `@ObservedObject` line and one on the line `let scene = xiangcene()`. One is what you're passing to `SpriteView` and the other is what you use in the `Button` action. You need to have *one* instance.

Comment: Your edit hasn’t changed anything — you are still creating two instances.

Comment: jnpdx hi. i change the @ObservedObject var scene = xiangcene() to skc = xiangcene() ,but it still no work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time you call `xiangcene()`, you're creating a *new instance* of `xiangcene`. Instead, you need to create *one instance* that is stored on the view, passed to the `SpriteView`, and manipulated by the button.

Here's one solution:

```
struct xiang: View {
    @StateObject var skc : xiangcene
    
    init() {
        let scene = xiangcene()
        scene.scaleMode = .fill
        _skc = StateObject(wrappedValue: scene)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack{
            SpriteView(scene: skc)
            Button("timeset"){
                skc.time1 = 60
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's another:

```
struct xiang: View {
    @StateObject var skc = xiangcene()
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack{
            SpriteView(scene: skc)
            Button("timeset"){
                skc.time1 = 60
            }
        }.onAppear {
            skc.scaleMode = .fill
        }
    }
}
```

Note that in both places, I'm using `StateObject` rather than `ObservedObject`, which is what I assume you want, but you can change that if that's an incorrect assumption.

I'd also consider using the Swift conventions of capitalizing type names -- it'll make it easier for people to read/parse your code.